# Alter array rows to be associative and append an additional associative element

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array, array-combine

I've created a method that allows me to assign keys to rows of values, and appends extra keys and values.

It adds all the new keys to a keys array, then adds all new values to the values array, and then combines all the keys and values.

How can I shrink it to make it smaller and more efficient?

```
$valores = array(array("1","1","1","1"),array("2","2","2","2"));//array of values
$keys = array('k1','k2','k3','k4'); //array of keys
$id = array('SpecialKey' => 'SpecialValue');//new array of items I want to add

function formatarArray($arrValores,$arrKeys,$identificadores){
    foreach($identificadores as $k => $v){
        array_push($arrKeys, $k);
    }
    
    foreach($arrValores as $i => $arrValor)
    {
        foreach($identificadores as $k => $v){
         array_push($arrValor, $v);
         }
         $arrValores[$i] = array_combine($arrKeys, $arrValor);
    }
    var_export($arrValores);
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'k1' => '1',
    'k2' => '1',
    'k3' => '1',
    'k4' => '1',
    'SpecialKey' => 'SpecialValue',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'k1' => '2',
    'k2' => '2',
    'k3' => '2',
    'k4' => '2',
    'SpecialKey' => 'SpecialValue',
  ),
)
```

**Viper-7(code debug):**
http://viper-7.com/hbE1YF

Comment: I didn't mean edit the tag, I meant that the question belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com (linked in my first comment) and not on stackoverflow.com

Comment: Should I delete this question?

Comment: You might be able to have a moderator migrate it instead of actually deleting it. I'm not really sure though, as I've never done it myself.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll ask them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function formatarArray($arrValores, $arrKeys, $identificadores)
{
    foreach ($arrValores as &$arr)
        $arr = array_merge(array_combine($arrKeys, $arr), $identificadores);
    print_r($arrValores);
}
```

Could even be done in one line...

```
function formatarArray($arrValores, $arrKeys, $identificadores)
{
    print_r(array_map(function ($arr) use ($arrKeys, $identificadores) { return array_merge(array_combine($arrKeys, $arr), $identificadores); }, $arrValores));
}
```

Comment: But can you tell me which one would be the most efficient?

Comment: They would perform practically the same, but the first one is better for readability so I'd chose it for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

As a modernized form of @havenard's answer, I'd use PHP7.4's arrow function syntax to avoid the need for `use()` and I would use the array union operator (`+`) to avoid the iterated `array_merge()` calls.  The array union operator is appropriate because it is adding an associative array to another array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GtuXL))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($row) => array_combine($keys, $row) + $id,
        $valores
    )
);
```